# Error coming in compilation of C code on Oracle Linux 7.2

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to compile a C code on Oracle Linux 7.2 which is hosted as VM on windows 10.

Name of file run: `configure`

Name of log file: `confg.log`

Error where I am stuck

> gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'

As per my understanding of the code structure so far, there is a file named `configure` which is having compilation related commands and this file generates Makefile.am which further generates Makefile.in and at last Makefile.

Please help me in solving the error and also let me know if my understanding about the configure and makefiles is incorrect

Comment: Possibly -v instead of -V for verbose output.

Comment: @cup `-V` is for version

Comment: The question need some real information. What are you trying to compile? Is it code you wrote, or something you downloaded? If the former, show us the code. If the later, give us some info.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca No, `-V` is unknown to gcc (at least to gcc 4.7.2 and 5.4.0 which I have access to) and produces exactly the error message quoted by the OP. The version is obtained by `--version`.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider my bad, I misinterpreted the man page for `gcc`. It looks like `-V` is for cross-compiling, in certain conditions. Look for -V on https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc

Comment: The earlier error  is resolved after replacing -V with -v. But now I am getting the same error for "-qversion" gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'

Comment: See my answer. Question: Does the configure script actually produce a Makefile? Then your errors may not be true errors but just configure script exploration.

Comment: Even I am not very sure about this at this point of time in terms of the relation between configure file and the makefiles.
Please help me with the same

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Apparently that is an option which was removed in newer (still a couple years old) gcc versions. It is present e.g. in [version 4.2.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.4/gcc/Target-Options.html#Target-Options) but not any longer in e.g. [5.4.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/Target-Options.html#Target-Options). The linux.die.net man page unfortunately does not provide a version number which is regrettable; but the last copyright is 2009 which sounds suspicious because they appear to diligently renew it every year ;-).

Comment: Well, you can be sure if you delete (or move to a different name) the makefile, run `configure` and magically have a new one ;-).

Comment: please update name of software you are trying to compile in the question

Answer (score 1):

`configure` scripts explore the environment in which a program is to be built. They then accordingly adjust tools called, options used and libraries linked, among other things. Some of the information is obtained by trying to execute programs with certain options; failure of a program to run is the intended way of obtaining the information that the given program is not available or does not take those options. Therefore it is not necessarily an error if one of the things doesn't work and produces an error; it may be one of the legitimate outcomes, and the (error, here) exit code of the compiler will be used to modify the Makefile accordingly — for example by omitting `-V` ;-).

Does the configure script actually stop there, or are you just observing the error in the log file? If you search for `gcc -V`  on the web you'll find examples of configure scripts failing actually *later* (for unrelated reasons) which have the same "`-V`  error" line in it. Could that be the case? I would assume that errors which actually cause `configure` to stop and not produce a Makefile should be visible on the command line, not only in the log file.

As an aside it is worthwhile to run `./configure --help`  and look through the options. Some may improve the build process or the result; for example you can usually tell configure that you are using `gcc`, gnu `ld` and so on, or that you don't need certain features (like X25 ;-) ).

Comment: Yes I am seeing this error in the log file. The script has not stopped here. I just started trying to resolve the errors one by one

Comment: There will be more errors, and as I said, only the one which stops the script is relevant ;-). If a Makefile is produced (and runs) all is well.

Comment: gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
conftest.c:11:28: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
conftest.c:11:28: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
conftest.c:50:28: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
| /* Override any GCC internal prototype to avoid an error.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:12930: error: X25 requested but is missing.
Last one may be

Comment: @PankajGupta If the configure script misses something (like X25) it obviously needs to be installed. The details depend on your Linux flavor and method of installation. I have no experience with Oracle Linux specifically, sorry. (Embarrassingly, I didn't know it existed until now.) If you *compile* programs dependent on other software (as opposed to just *using* a pre-compiled binary) you'll need the *-dev" versions of those software packages; by default they are only installed as runtime libraries, without headers.

Comment: Oh, and many `configure` scripts give the user the opportunity to disable certain features they don't need in that software. Chances are you don't need X25 (unless you are installing some networking software which deals with old protocols). Perhaps you can say something like `--no-X25` or `--no-packet-switching` on the command line.-- Another thing is that generally large software projects have mailing lists on which one can ask questions which are specific to that project. Failing build scripts certainly fall in that category, except if they fail because one of the prerequisites  isn't met.

Answer (score -1):

You should look into the `makefile` of your project, identify where the misspelled `-V` option is and replace it with `-v` (lowercase). As pointed out by others in the comments `-V` is not a compiling flag, but gives back the compiler's version.

Comment: My gcc 5.4.0 (I obtained the version with `gcc --version`) for cygwin does not know a `-V` option (with capital V). It knows a `-v` option which makes it "Display the programs invoked by the compiler" (as you may know, the gcc executable is a mere front end for the preprocessor, actual compiler and linker). The OP's error message is the same as the one my gcc issues when called with `-V`.

Comment: The earlier one is resolved after replacing -V with -v. But now I am getting the same error for "-qversion"

gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'